# MySQL : Find out what the state was of a row on a certain date

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a database which contains

- calls and the state of a call (incoming / Answered / Callback / etc)
- History of state transition : ex. on 1st of March  at 9 AM call-id 100 went from state incoming to state answered

I would like to write a query which could summarize how many calls were on Callback at a given date.
Although I have quite some experience in MySQL, I lack the knowledge to find the right function and Google didn't really help me to find a solution

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the last status of calls as of a certain date.  One method is aggregation and a correlated subquery:

```
select state, count(*)
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t
                where t2.date < '2021-03-09' and
                      t2.call_id = t.call_id
               )
group by state;
```

This returns the state of all calls at the beginning of 2021-03-09.

Comment: That seems promising :-) How would I be able to extract this for multiple days, so I can see the evolution? Would I need to do a query for every single day in that case?

Comment: @MaartenKesselaers . . . For now, I would suggest multiple queries. If you have lots of days, there might be better approaches.  But if you just want to look at the migration for a week or so, separate queries might be the simplest method.